# Vue.js updating a value upon deselecting a checkbox

Tags: javascript

Check out my fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jqumt5oy/

I'm using a simple array to populate my table:

```
    data: {
        groceries: [
            { description: 'Chicken', price: 1, number: 4, selected: true },
            { description: 'Beef', price: 2, number: 0, selected: false },
            { description: 'Beer', price: 3, number: 2, selected: true },
            { description: 'Milk', price: 4, number: 0, selected: false }
        ]
    },
```

How would I update the number of a row to zero when deselecting a checkbox? So when I want to leave something out of my list, I just have to deselect it, instead of first manually updating the number to 0?

I'm going to guess I would need a function for that, or can it be done easier by binding another v-model to the select menu for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it using a method:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-model="grocery.selected" @click="selectNumber(grocery)">

    methods: {

        selectNumber: function(grocery) {
            if(grocery.selected == true)
            {
                grocery.number = 0;
                grocery.selected = 0;
            }
        }

    }
```

If anyone has a better solution, please feel free to post one.